# Can I close my question after I accept?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, etiquette, close-reasons

Can I close my question only the answer remaining on the page that voters could not vote on the post?

Comment: I ***hate*** that attitude: "*My* problem is solved, so the question can go away now."  Your question *might* be useful to other people who use similar search terms.

Comment: You mean you want to *delete* the question; it is already *closed*.  Well, tough.  (1) The people that answered it might deserve their positive rep, (2) Your question might help the next guy with his search. (3) The negative votes should serve you as a reminder of the importance of doing even a little digging before asking -- although that can be harder for newbies and ESL users.

Comment: Please do _not_ deface your question here. You asked a question and got an answer. Meta votes express disagreement with an idea, not a judgement on quality of this question itself.

Comment: downvotes that continue piling on this question remind me of infamous **[The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773 "'closed as too localized', yeah sure - just take a look at questions linked to it")**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is already closed as a duplicate.

But generally if you like to close a question you can flag it for closure or if you have enough reputation (3k+) you can cast a close vote.

You cannot delete your question if it has answers with positive score.

Comment: It is closed. Closed means you can't add new answers, but still downvote.

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: @C-Link The comments on your question seem to provide a reasonable explanation for the downvotes.

Comment: Whao only mod can lock post none of us can do

Comment: I really feel bad about accepted answer's op that when your post is deleted ...his true efforts will deleted :(

Comment: Ahh  Your account is ban for asking question ... than try giving some good answer so that you may get rep and ban will lifted up

Comment: When you are banned from asking questions then you should read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) carefully.

Comment: I have read that very carefully but I could not know that when I'll be removed from this ban after my scores top?

Comment: I can't give you any additional info that is not included in that link.

Comment: undelete your deleted question / downvoted question and  improve them

Answer (score 2):

As the downvote tooltip says, one of the reasons for downvoting is that the question "*does not show any research effort*". Since your question is a duplicate of another question, it shows that you didn't do significative previous research.

BTW, please refrain from your editing practice of replacing **all** the content with a one-line comment. It is difficult to see what you had asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is duplicate of css id vs class and already closed .. its always good to do some search hefore posting questiin

And closing doesn't mean that vote on post is locked and also you can not delete closed question