# Are questionnaires permitted on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, questions, scope

Is it OK to post a questionnaire on Stack Exchange sites?

I'm currently working on a project at my uni and need some empirical information about workouts. I want to explain more about the project, but that will come if it's "legal" to post a questionnaire here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask  No. surveys are not permitted.

Comment: For workout related things, maybe check out fitness.SE: http://fitness.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for asking first, instead of being like the (many) people who just post whatever they want and then complain when the questions get closed.

Comment: Okay :( thx for the answer btw, much appreciated.

But giving me the minus points, does it mean that its a rubbish question or? I was just asking

Comment: And thx Richard i will check it out

Comment: @user2151779 votes are [different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Oh okay, im sorry. Im pretty new here and gets confused by all the rules.
But thx for the answer

Comment: @Sancho I think this time it means the OP should have read the [FAQ].

Comment: @Sancho in the light of the accepted answer, question downvotes mean infamous [“I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773 "'closed as too localized'... yeah sure, just look at the list of linked questions")

Comment: @JoshCaswell What gave you the impression that this question was asking about *Meta*? You did notice that it was originally asked on Stack Overflow and then migrated here, right? Methinks you completely changed the question (and therefore the answer).

Comment: @CodyGray: I did _not_ notice the migration. You're quite right, my edit was erroneous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[No. Surveys are not permitted.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Link only answer, flagged. J/K.

Comment: I'm bored of encouraging people to write their answers as _answers_, not comments. So I'm just going to steal your answers instead, until you get it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Teehee

Comment: Two downvotes. Nice.

Comment: You're complaining about 2 downvotes when you got 13 upvotes for an answer that took you 30 seconds to write? (Or maybe my joke/sarcasm detector is broken, in which case, hahaha.)

Comment: @Doorknob Well I'm not trying to suggest that it's the end of the world. Just noting that some people are silly! The upvotes are irrelevant when discussing the downvotes, see.