# Vote to reopen an ancient question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174744/why-did-non-von-neumann-languages-never-became-mainstream

This is an ancient (by SO standards) question closed 2+1/2 years ago as "Not a real question". The question is broad and imperfectly formulated, but is interesting, essentially sound, and received a superb answer by Norman Ramsey. It is a decent question, and it would be good for us if we did not signal that such questions are not unwelcome.

<s>Please vote to reopen! Or at least tell me why I am wrong about this...</s>

### Postscript

Thanks for your input.  I withdraw the request.

Comment: You're right, it should not have been closed as *not a real question*. It should have been closed as *not constructive* instead.

Comment: Prime candidate for deletion or migration to Programmers, in my opinion.

Comment: @oded - Deletion would be pure vandalism

Comment: "Or at least tell me why I am wrong about this..." -> "The question is broad and imperfectly formulated..."

Comment: Vandalism? It would be removal of unsuitable content from the site. I may be persuaded to lock it, but it is not a good question for SO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Maybe, but it isn't obvious to me.  It is true that it is often not clear why things worked out the way they did, but it is not always unclear.  This is not "which is the best non-Von Neumann language?"

Comment: @Charles, honestly, I do not think "what didn't X catch up" questions are any more constructive than "which is the best X" ones.

Comment: The answer is essentially saying "Nobody can say for certain, but here are some possible factors that may have been the cause." That to me seems like it would fail the "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise" criteria of "not constructive" so it would just be closed again even if it was reopened.

Comment: Voting to reopen _this_ question, because it is a valid -- if unpopular -- request to make. For the record, I think the SO post in question should remain closed.

Comment: thoughtless downvotes piling on this question despite the edits and in the light of the accepted answer, remind of infamous [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773 "'closed as too localized' yeah sure just take a look at the list of linked question")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the closed reason that was chosen was incorrect.  It is a real question but it is not constructive.  This should not be reopened and if it is, it should be closed as not-constructive:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance.

The question is going to solicit debate on why non-von Neumann languages never became mainstream.

Comment: Indeed, the well-written answer begins with "no one knows the answer".

Comment: It didn't solicit that debate in the several days it was open back when SO was less clear about what kind of debate was unwelcome.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Well it doesn't the fit the standards of the site today and should stay closed.  Like I said, if it is reopened then I would vote to close as not-constructive or even off-topic for SO.

Comment: @CharlesStewart - The first comment on that - "should be community wiki" tells you that it is not a suitable question.

Comment: @Oded - All kinds of questions used to attract that comment for bad reasons.

Comment: Possibly, but it is clear from that comment that not everyone thought it was a good question as such. It was mostly used for poll type question, which this question suffers from.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since if it is not the answer I would like to be true, I guess it is clear that is how we police the constructive/  non-constructive boundary now, and I suppose even back then.