# What makes this question "too localized"?

Tags: support, specific-question, meta, timeline, too-localized

This question has been closed as too localized: [The "I Get It" Reputation Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

As far as I can tell, [question timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/552/timeline) suggests rather reliable (though not quite impressive) *flow of interest*, as indicated by upvotes and comments that seem to come in once a month on average for about half year since it has been closed.

Question has about 1K views which put it in 2% top viewed [at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A1000) and in [reputation tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[reputation]+views%3A1000)  (again, not particularly impressive, but not quite *very low interest*, either).

I would like to understand how to match above observations with closure notice?

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to... an extraordinarily narrow situation...

Comment: 1K views _in 3 years_ isn't that much. That said, "not constructive" might have been a bit more suitable there than "too localized".

Comment: It was 4 years ago. Haven't the rules on closing/deleting questions changed since then?

Comment: It is not closed as Too localized. It is open.

Comment: @DanielDaranas question has been **reopened** few hours after I asked about it, I [self-answered with this update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181627/165773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has been reopened: [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/552/revisions)

> **Post Reopened** by [Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts), [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker)♦

Answer (score 2):

I would venture a guess that it was closed as too localized because it was asking about a specific case. The interest generated seems to be more on the general topic.

Had it been worded as a more general feature request, I think it would have remained open and likely would have received even more attention.

Comment: If that's true, shouldn't all questions tagged specific-question be closed as too localized?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not saying that it should have been closed. Just guessing as to why it was. Honestly I think it should have stayed open. By the way, do you have the ability and or desire to remedy this situation?