# How to hide negative reputation in the reputation history?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I want to hide negative reputation which appears in the reputation history. I want to know the

settings do so.

**Edited:**

[Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

This was the answer i needed at last i found by my own, this is the mistake of stack overflow, really fedup of dwonvotes..!!!! annoying..!!

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Did someone serial up-vote you, and then get removed? This is a **most** unusual occurrence.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels might be..!!

Comment: Now everyone will go to your profile and see the negative reputation. If you hadn't asked this question, few people would have noticed. See [Streisand Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect).

Comment: my bad time..!!

Comment: instead of downvoting you guys could have flaged the question..!! all the downvoters come and flag this question now..!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters what you are about to say?? i have posted the link in my post and found it as answer, now you are marking as duplcate???

Comment: Yes, you say in your post that that's the answer you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: Please help me to close the question

Comment: Flag it for closing\

Comment: @MartijnPieters - But question's title, main body, and answer are not duplicate. Just an edit is. I think it should be rolled back and/or converted to the comment. This can pretty stand open as a separate question.

Comment: @hims056 can you please help me to close this question

Comment: @hims056: This question is of *terrible* quality. It was not clear what the OP was talking about; as it turns out this is about the loss of vote reputation when a user is deleted. We can either close this as "unclear what you are asking", or follow the OPs directions that that question answered what he was looking for and close this as a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters close this question

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: I have already voted to close. Note that closing the question won't lock the votes; if people still want to downvote this post they can do so even when closed.

Comment: recommended reading: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem)

Comment: It is sad when people downvote support questions in a support forum.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there is no option to hide negative reputation in our reputation history. Why do one need to hide it? If you have negative reputation, don't care of what people will think, just accept it and move on.

Comment: Well... the -770 in his history does look pretty bad. I won't speculate what it was. But it's definitely a motive to want to hide it.

Comment: @Mysticial yup, i just got a message that user was removed :(

Comment: @Mysticial - If -770 is because of my own fault (you know for what) I will accept it. If it's not my fault I will not care for it.

Comment: It does make me wonder about sock-puppet votes. 1+ for the answer.

Comment: @hims056 so it is better not to care of it..!! :(

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: it is your **only** option.