# How can I request my question to be locked?

Tags: support, reputation, moderation, locked-questions, locked-votes

My question titled, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259072/should-there-be-a-grace-period-before-you-can-down-vote-a-post, is receiving a tremendous amount of down-votes and comment criticism.

The thing is, I already understand that my question isn't so great. But every day, that question gathers more and more down-votes, and I keep losing reputation points.

> [image: I already understand that my question isn't so great, but I'm still accumulating more and more down-votes.]
> I already understand that my question isn't so great, but I'm still accumulating more and more down-votes every day.

I don't want my reputation to continue draining just because of a disliked question that's been sitting there for a long time. It's like trying to fill a bowl with water, except the bowl has a large hole in it.

Is it possible to request my question to be locked? Locked questions can't be voted or commented on, although they're still accessible. I want other users to be able to read the question and its answers, but I don't want them to keep up the down-vote frenzy.

A Related Question : [The "I Get It" Reputation Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem)

Comment: I don't think you can lock your posts - I suppose you could flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be done. But, the fact is, you wrote that post and the community disagreed.

Comment: You can't delete it in any case; it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Now this is so ironic: a question asking to stop losing rep is getting downvoted making me lose rep.

Comment: And comments like that can actually cause you to lose even more rep - stop focusing on the rep!

Comment: Sometimes downvoted question and answer helps other people to learn

Comment: So you want people to not be able to downvote you. Maybe ask the team to simply suspend anyone who dares downvote you?

Comment: @NarawaGames You're quite right.  Asking questions about how to stop losing rep when that rep loss is entirely justified is going to result in you losing more rep.  Either fix the problem that is causing the post to be downvoted, or accept it gracefully.

Comment: @NarawaGames Shadow was being sarcastic....

Comment: @Servy was I? ;)

Comment: locking it would not be a good choice, other members may wish to add an answer that would be beneficial for future readers.

Comment: see also: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/165773)

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe. Next time, pay more attention to the buttons you click.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd suggest you to just forget about it and move on - I'm having [tons of much-downvoted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a259214%20score%3a..-1) (you can also scroll to the end of this search) and don't complain.

However you can still flag it to be locked or deleted, though I'm pretty sure your flag would be declined. No other options. You can't even delete it yourself, because it has up voted answers.

Also, maybe this would be a bit soothing. That question and any down voted questions of yours on meta don't mean you can't ask or your questions are certainly bad... Just community disagrees with you.

(Some more small suggestions: I'd Stop Capitalizing Each Letter Of The Title, at least because it looks pretty spammy; [faking the data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259072/should-there-be-a-grace-period-before-you-can-down-vote-a-post#comment844540_259072) isn't really great too)

Comment: I actually agree with you on this one - (don't faint!)

Comment: If my flag gets declined, Stack Exchange will get suspicion and ban me. I've got a lot of declined flags already!

Comment: Every time I ask a question, I get down-voted and the answerer gets up-voted. I lost more than 50 rep!

Comment: @Narawa Don't worry, I'm sure you are not the only one. Solution? Answer :D

Comment: @NarawaGames it is probably because people disagree with your question and agree with the answer

Comment: @san *raises eyebrows* :D

Comment: @nicael I know, I'm scared too

Comment: Lots of declined flags means you won't be able to flag anymore for a while, that's all. No permanent ban, @Narawa.

Comment: `That question and any down voted questions of yours on meta don't mean you can't ask or your questions are bad`  It can mean that though, and in the case of this user, that is almost certainly a factor in the downvotes he's gotten.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, unless a mod gets sufficiently annoyed at your inappropriate flagging and manually bans you.  If they feel you're intentionally spamming the flag system, and not just bad at flagging, they may do that.

Comment: @Servy I rephrased; however I don't consider their previous question to be really bad-written (except for capitaled title? I edited it). I'd say there's more disagreement.

Comment: @nicael If you read the comments on the question with the most downvotes it's filled with people explaining why it's a bad question, not just people saying why it's a bad idea.  I imagine there's quite a bit of *both*, rather than just one or the other.

Comment: "That question and any down voted questions of yours on meta don't mean you can't ask or your questions are bad..." I got a question ban.

Answer (score 12):

Nothing that you can do to that question - and nothing that needs to be done.

One aspect to consider is that [your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259072/should-there-be-a-grace-period-before-you-can-down-vote-a-post) that has caused your rep decline (or 'repscapade' *credit to [Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/288751/tiny-giant)*) is something you have to take responsibility for.  Take the loss of rep as a lesson learned - leave it alone and the question will be buried in the Stack Exchange sands of time.

What do you need to take responsibility for and learn from?

- Not doing your research first, hence the duplicates.
- Lying, embellishing the downvotes in the image, then trying to 'cover it up' with a cropped image (which is still visible in the [edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/259072/revisions)!) - it is very obvious that the question in the image was not at -25, so your evidence for your premise was false.

And your subsequent comments continuously complaining about the loss of rep, both here and on MSO are ***NOT*** going to help you in any way.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to stop and spend some time reading and learning how this site works.

In the meantime, if that post is too much of an anchor weighing you down, you can request that it be disassociated from your account. Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, choose the "Other" reason, and explain your situation.

Once you've done that, I suggest *you stop posting here*, at least for a while. In your short time here you have posted a whole bunch of feature requests that were asked for and rejected long ago. A quick search through the archives would have found them and would have saved you from the downvotes for "lack of research".

Most of your other posts have obviously not been well-received, and seem to simply be from someone who doesn't understand how this site (or the other sites in the Network) works. There is *a lot* of history here. You should spend a little time getting familiar with how things work.

And do please note: A downvote on a post of yours is not an attack against you personally. It's a judgment of the content of your post. No one is being *mean* to you, although perhaps some people feel that you're being disrespectful with your poorly researched posts.

Answer (score 6):

Historical locks are reserved for the very rare cases where the community fights amongst itself about the existence of a question. They aren't to be used to prevent downvotes.

There isn't any conflict around your question. You presented a feature request that had been rejected before. The community disagreed with it, and marked it as a duplicate of previous discussions around the same idea. All of that was handled without controversy, so there's no need for moderators to step in here.

Sorry that you don't like losing reputation points over it, but that's no reason to lock a post.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to request moderator attention to your own question? I can't flag it myself, or else it'll be declined, leading me to a flag-ban.

I'll assume that "your" is supposed to be "my" in this case. The only way you can get moderator attention is by flagging your own post for moderator attention or literally, have a moderator look at your question, which is like every single time someone brings in a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Or have someone else do the dirty work for you. But as you said, **the flag will be declined**.

Really, don't do anything. Just leave it there as reminders of what you should not ask in this site. I mean I have a nice list of negatively voted questions myself. I'm actually question-banned on Stack Overflow...

Anyways, learn from your mistakes. You lost 34 rep today (number subject to change for the good I hope). If you see why you got downvoted, fix the problem and you're okay. For [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions, downvotes are given because your fellow users do not like the contents of which you are suggesting. Nothing much here.

Locking your questions might go too far. They are rarely seen and usually because of controversy of the existence of the post itself. Since the question has answers, they lock it rather than delete the post. We all know that losing rep can be painful but just deal with it, and learn from your mistakes.