# What is the effect of popular bad quality question in the long run?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Today I received a popular badge for one of my bad questions, it has 3 downvotes. Many of us ask bad questions sometimes, sometimes when we are new to the system. Popular questions would show on search engines more often.

And I can't delete it because it has good answers, and there's little I can do to improve it, it was just bad. If someone else asked it I would've downvote it immediately, when I received the badge, I couldn't believe I asked it honestly. Even if I could improve, I just don't want to look at it, I hate it.

Today I have 3 downvotes, if I receive 1 downvote a year, means after 10 years it will have 13 downvotes and I will be banned because of a question I asked 10 years earlier. Wouldn't that happen?

Comment: Have you considered deleting your account and starting over?

Comment: You won't be banned because you have 1 question at -13...

Comment: @random I have good rep, if I delete my account, I lose everything, and all links to many other accounts, I have been using this site for more than 5 years I guess

Comment: @Servy yes but this is more of a general question, not for my case only. Some people ask different low quality questions, it doesn't mean much now, but a downvote every year, shouldn't downvoting have a time span?

Comment: @Lynob My statement would apply to anyone.  Having a -13 will never get you banned.  You would need to also have other poor contributions, and few/no positive contributions.

Comment: somewhat related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: @Servy what is this about having -13 being banned anyways, i've not heard it before

Comment: @Cursed1701 You just said the opposite of what I said...

Comment: @servy I'm not disagreeing, I'm just asking as to what this is and how they got this -13 thing from

Comment: @Cursed1701 You're asking what a question with a score of -13 is?  It's a question with a score of -13...

Comment: @Servy hilarious, but I'm pretty sure you know I meant what is -13 in terms of getting banned, which the OP seemed to think was a feature, is this true, and if not where could they have heard it

Comment: @Cursed1701 So you're asking me if you can get banned for having a question with a score of -13 when I specifically said that you can't get banned for having a question with a score of -13... Are you expecting my answer to have changed since yesterday?  No, you won't get banned for having a question with a score of -13.

Comment: @Servy I think he's asking the following, in terms of percentage, statistically speaking, how closer are you to getting banned, if you have a -13 question, statistically, and mathematically speaking, what is the probability - And I think no one knows the answer because no one knows the algorithm that bans people and how it weighs the downvotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things that might comfort you:

- You're not necessarily going to get one downvote per year. Question views typically trickle off over time, meaning that voting rates on a question drop.
- You're not going to get question-banned because you asked one question that got a bunch of downvotes. Currently, about 10% of your 111 questions have negative scores. This one won't hurt you. Over time, you can improve this ratio.
- You're not necessarily going to just get downvotes over the next X years, especially if you figure out what's wrong with your question and fix it.

Comment: So no need to stop old questions from being downvoted right?

Comment: @Lynob I don't see a reason to do so, unless it needs a lock for moderation purposes.

Comment: no worries - should've been obvious in hindsight

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @HDE226868's great answer, if the question has a good answer, I am sure you can improve your post. After editing it, you can leave a comment in the edit summary along the lines of

> I edited the question to make it more clear and useful.

Some users might upvote your question after reading your edit and comment. I usually do.

Also, if you really don't want to edit your question, you could try to flag your own question for a moderator's attention and ask him/her to delete the question explaining in detail why you want to delete it. I've had a similar experience and got a few of my questions deleted. Try to be as specific as possible.